# Draw custom rectangle shape with canvas or svg, which has support for IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, svg

I need some direction to draw the following custom shape rectangle with canvas or svg Or even with css, which has support for IE7.

any Javascript Jquery plugin welcome.

http://jsfiddle.net/349x9/1087/
thanks

Comment: Canvas and SVG with IE7.  Now that's funny.  Thanks for making my day!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Raphael. Use your points in the code for the coordinates you need for the path.
You create a "canvas" with the Raphael command...

For the simple command to initialize the canvas go here...

http://raphaeljs.com/

Play with path straight away here..
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?q=paper.path

Answer (score 0):

Since Canvas element does not work in IE7 I would suggest you to use excanvas. It is a simple JavaScript which would help you to render Canvas on your page. It is used simply by adding it to the header of your page and then just adding canvas element and doing your usual stuff on the page.

I have updated it here http://jsfiddle.net/349x9/1088/ I have actually saved the sample. Check it on IE the link to excanvas is http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

The best tutorials for Canvas can be found below:-

- [html5canvastutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/)
- [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML%3aCanvas)
- [html5_ref_canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_canvas.asp)

For Knowing different frameworks to work further with canvas refer this link

- [10-javascript-canvas-frameworks](http://www.backslash.gr/content/blog/webdevelopment/7-10-javascript-canvas-frameworks) For some advance/intuitive/creative work

Comment: How do we make that custom shape out of canvas. I have problem with doing that. and I want to add some text inside it. thanks

Comment: @Semantic I have mentioned some websites that are best for canvas tutorials and some Frameworks that will help you while handling canvas. Check my post I have reedited it and added those Links.

Answer (score 0):

CSS border triangles are a solution that works in IE7, with no JavaScript required: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/3WLXa/3/).

Another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/Sg3xe/5/) showing the 4 types of right triangles.

Comment: very intresting Matt, I will have a look into this. let see if that works for me.

Comment: I found a fix for the blurry antialiasing of diagonal edges in Firefox and updated the demos.